# Which IP address belongs to which printer

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-xp, ip, printer

How to determine which IP address belongs to which printer Some wireles others hard conected

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Wireless Network Watcher from Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_network_watcher.html), it shows all the devices connected to your local network with its MAC Address and Network Adapter.

Comment: You could, but that doesn't actually answer the question ...